# What is the equivalent of WordPress category in Drupal websites for the purpose of SEO?

Tags: seo, drupal, categories

In WordPress website you can assign a category to each article to boost ranking for the category's keyword. How can I do this in Drupal websites?

Comment: You need to set up a Taxonomy. You can call the taxonomy "Category" and then create categories as the actual terms.

Comment: @WebElaine please don't post answers as comments.   What you posted is a little short, but with a link to Drupal documentation it would be a great answer.

Comment: I am not of the opinion that WordPress categories are good for SEO.  They often hurt SEO.  Yes, WP creates a page for the category and automatically populates it with snippets and links to tagged posts.  However, category pages are generally poor SEO landing pages.  They look a lot like search results pages, like the one the user just left.   That isn't the best user experience and users often get frustrated by it.   Users generally want to land on higher quality pages.

Comment: It really depends on how you set up the category - how it's styled, what info is included. Some themes allow you to add text at the top summarizing it which can be beneficial. Overall they are just another page to optimize - they're not inherently good or bad for SEO, it's all in how you use them.